# Can a dragon be aware of your immunity to their magic element?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If I have enchanted my armour with 100% resistance to both fire and frost and encounter a dragon that uses the aforementioned elements, will said dragon be able to notice it's shout attack is not affecting me and resort to melee, or will it shout regardless of the fact that it is not doing damage?

Comment: As far as i know, dragon doesn't see your hp bar, thus is not aware of you not suffering damage. He'll just keep shooting if you're too far away and melee if close. But since Skyrim isn't installed on my computer at the moment, i cannot make sure of it right now, you'll have to wait for confirmation from someone else.

Comment: The premise to the question is flawed. You can't become immune to breath attacks this way. There's an 85% cap for each element as well as an 85% cap for magic resist. These can be stacked for up to 97.75% resistance, but you still aren't immune. Without the unofficial patch, a vampire player with the Restoration perk Necromage will have 100% spell absorption if they first get the afore mentioned disease and perk, then get the Atronach Perk in Alteration and the Atronach Stone. Necromage on vampires buffs those by 25% each to 37.5% and 62.5% respectively. Dragon's still breathe on you, though.

Comment: Another thought regarding the enemy AI of casters in general(including dragons since their shouts use up some of their magicka pool). When I'm low level and have less than optimal enchantments(a couple random shields with either fire or shock resist for example) I may encounter a mage who starts shooting flame spells at me. I pop on the appropriate shield and all the sudden the mage switches to shock. I switch to that shield and the mage switches to frost.WTF? Maybe I have a magic resist shield I can switch to. Saw somewhere dragons know if followers are immune(not limited like you). No fight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  No enemies in skyrim are aware of your magic immunity.  The dragon AI is quite simple.  If you are not in melee range, it'll use its breath and shouts at you.  If you are in melee range, then it'll try to chomp you.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answer said, no, they will keep shooting their breath at you. If you don't want them to, you can use something that does shock damage. Dragons have a magicka pool too. Once they run out, they will resort to melee.